# There is no 5-minute edit window when using the in-page retagging tool

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, 10k-tools, inline-tag-editor

See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/35774/revisions

The first edit I did through the editing page, but I realized I forgot to add `[tags]` and used the in-page editor. The two edits were 10 seconds apart, but the second one generated a new revision (not what I would have expected).

I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design. I'd prefer if there was an edit window in this situation, but I understand that it probably doesn't come up that often. I just figured to report it in case this is not what Jeff & company intended to have happen.

---

<strike>**EDIT:** Another case of no edit window here (revisions 2 and 3): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/52835/revisions</strike>

I used the inline tool for my edit, and the 2nd edit was within 5 minutes, yet it generated a new revision. Note also that the 2nd edit contained the exact same content as my edit, except for the commentary. When the post was at revision 3, I was unable to rollback to revision 2 (I think this is probably a separate issue, but just mentioning). (We have determined this behaviour is not isolated to the inline tag editing tool.)

---

**UPDATE:** Is this [fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/52874/revisions) now? That was actually an inline edit and two manual edits combined in one revision.

Comment: This also occurs when you use "retag" as a <2k, but not when you reach 2k and use "edit" to do naught but two retags.

Comment: @ccomet: Interesting! Maybe there is already a bug report for this. Searching...

Comment: @ccomet: Hmm... can't find anything on it. Maybe no one noticed/cared. LOL

Comment: Hmm, I'd test it here but don't want to turn your question CW.

Comment: @mmyers: I made a test question. You can edit it now since it's been up for > 5 minutes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52839/edit-window-test-question

Comment: You're right, edits 9 seconds apart registered separately. Definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: [Here's the link from the earlier comment discussion about falsely attributed edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/bug-report-so-says-i-made-a-change-that-i-didnt-make).

Comment: I want to test something with regards to the second portion of this question. Can someone start and complete an edit on the 52839 test question? (@mmyers to blink)

Comment: @ccomet: READYSETGO!

Comment: @ccoment: Oops. Guess I should have made a tag edit to be consistent. Oh well. We can try again if this doesn't work.

Comment: @ccomet: That did it! I can't roll back to my edit either. Although, I think that actually debunks that the inline editing tool is to blame for the second revision in that case. I will edit the question here.

Comment: @Jon It's not related to the 5 minute edit window (at least, I'm certain it isn't directly related). And I know exactly the steps to reproduce it (and have an appropriate answer typed out for it). Should I post this here, wait for you to post a new question, or instead post the issue as a question myself?

Comment: @ccomet: If you think it's worth it's own bug/issue report, go ahead and start one yourself (I need to get back to work); if not, then add an answer here. Thanks!

Comment: I found it was already reported (sorta), and posted it as [an answer over there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/ignore-identical-revision-changes-in-edit-collisions/52846#52846)

Comment: Thought I'd just toss this out there, but on a random tangent, the strange simultaneous over-write thing which prevents you from being able to rollback? It seems to no longer prevent you from rolling back. Don't know under what circumstances this changed, but I noticed an old scenario in which it should've applied, and I no longer lack the ability to rollback.

Comment: @Grace: Oh, cool, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be pushed in tonight's build.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bug. Still.

From playing with this a bit more through normal use, it appears that whenever you use the inline retagging tool, a new revision is created, regardless of whether or not the retag takes place during the 5-minute window or not.

So if I retag a question using the inline tool, realize I made a mistake and use the inline tool *again* immediately following the first edit, the second action *will create a new revision*. If I had used the inline tool for the first edit, then used the full edit page for the second one, a new revision is *not* created.