# Revision history not displaying?

Tags: support, revisions-list

Is there a limit on updating post revisions? I have just noticed my revision history on an answer I made on SO about 20 minutes ago isn't showing any "last edited" or otherwise.

Is this a bug, or expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a 5 minute grace period after any edit (or initial post) during which edits by the original author do not create new revisions; is that what you're referring to?

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking. Thanks!

Comment: For those reading back who have 10k+ abilities, this isn't *completely* true yet. Here is the exception: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52734/there-is-no-5-minute-edit-window-when-using-the-in-page-retagging-tool @user