# Message about edit conflicts not working?

Tags: bug, edits, concurrency

[According to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6495/279180) [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65404/279180) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1577/279180) I should get a notification on saving if someone has saved before me.

In [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/187707/revisions), I saved 13 secs after A__, in revision 24. Both I and they deleted ", or is at the end of a line" because they say they will in a comment, and we both also changed something else. My edit overwrites theirs and I didn't get any notifications.

I didn't ask, but this may have happened again in revision 27. I have deleted two spaces in the last minute of the grace period of revision 26. After revision 27, 11 secs after the grace period, the spaces are back.

According to the screenshots, we are supposed to refresh and manually compare what has changed before saving again, which probably won't happen in a few seconds, even if (or especially if) they are just two insignificant spaces.

Comment: Yes looks like whatever Jeff put there got overwritten and forgotten about in the years that passed since then. As far as I know, there's nothing like that and never was.

Comment: Someone on one of our sites, (don't ask me where) explained to me that "... someone with 'edit permission' (high enough rep.) simply overwrites prior edits of users with lesser permission, and without notification ..." - but in that case it was my post's edit overwritten by a near simultaneous edit from a higher level user, whereas in your case it's your post and edit overwriting a lower rep user - so there would (also) be nothing to notify you about, you simply step on them; neither is notified. Possibly adding to the confusion is that your grace period edits aren't logged. +1 for using ░ .