# What will happen if more than one person edits the same question at the same time?

Tags: discussion, edits

I haven't seen this happen yet.

Comment: I posted a suggestion for getting around this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22135/optimistic-concurrency-for-post-edits. Doesn't seem to have garnered much interest though.

Comment: Note that TheTXI and me both began editing revision 1. He modified the body, and I modified the title and tags. Both changes were submitted, and both were preserved.

Answer (score 11):

Since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119), if a conflict occurs.

<s>The user who clicks "Save Your Edits" second will overwrite the first person's changes.</s>

There is no type of merging interface.

Comment: And if you're especially lucky, both editors will notice that someone has stepped on someone else's toes, and both will go in and attempt to merge manually, again overwriting one another's changes.  This continues until their mutual goodwill is detected as an edit war and both users are banned.

Comment: `...` unless one of them realize that they are fighting with Rich B. and gives up.

Comment: They don't give up.  They whine about it to a mod.

Comment: @Adam: Yet another reason why I **never** demonstrate good will.

Comment: Also, cue somebody posting a feature request for a merging interface...

Answer (score 7):

The universe will end, and a new one will be created, starting from the exact same moment that the last universe left off, with all of the exact same properties as the first universe, except with one fewer waffle.

In other words, every time two edits collide, random quantum fluctuations kill a waffle. **Please, think of the waffles.**

Note that his happens all the time. When I think my edits are going to take a long time, I leave a comment saying that I'll be editing it for a while. That way people know not to edit the question lest the universe be recreated.

Comment: **Edit in progress...**

Comment: Actually, you don't have that quite right. Every time two edits collide, **I** kill a waffle. (I like it when there are a lot of collisions on a Saturday morning.)

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, there is *limited* support for merging: if one editor edits only the title, and another edits only the body, then [both changes will be preserved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/24343/comments#comment-50976). Same goes for tags.

Comment: And, since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119), if a conflict is found in fields that were edited by both parties.

Answer (score 3):

Since the end of May 2011, [the more substantial edit will win](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247). There should also be an "n other users are editing this post" notification shown to all editors whenever a post is being edited by multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

Both users changes will show in the revision history, with the user that saves last overwriting the user that saves first.  There is no provision for locking or checking out to edit.  As you said, you've never noticed this, so it works pretty well.

Comment: Like the tortoise and the hare, being the slowest means you win!

Comment: No longer true: since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119), if a conflict occurs.