# "More thorough" edits?

Tags: support

When I recently experienced an edit collision, I got the (new and improved!) text:

> This post has been edited 1 time since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

How do I determine if my edit is "more thorough"? Does the system do that magically? (There's a lot of amazing magic here. :) Or am I supposed to gauge "more thorough"? How? I can't easily see the new text and my text side-by-side. Or did I miss how?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win

Comment: More specifically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247 gives the current standard for "thoroughness"

Comment: @Adam, @Anthony, excellent! Thanks. Voting to close :D