# Indicator of an ongoing edit?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits

Several times I've gone to edit an answer that needed improvement, only to find afterward that the author or another community member was already in the process of editing it. It would be nice to see who, if anyone, is currently editing a post, as some reassurance that my edits will be helpful or that needed edits are taking place.

Has this been considered? Are there any significant barriers to implementing it?

Comment: There's already [several things that happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247) in the case of concurrent edits. It seems that the inline editor doesn't do the heartbeat necessary to generate the topbar notification though. I could see that being `bydesign`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @TimStone Good catch; no, that's not by design. The heartbeat code was never updated to handle inline editing. That needs some fixin'.

Comment: @TimStone: Should work now.

Answer (score 4):

Ever since we refactored the editor and allowed inline-editing the old edit heartbeat has been disabled.

I just re-enabled it with an extra helpful link.

[image: edit heartbeat]

Comment: How do you measure thoroughness. Character count?

Comment: @random: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247

Comment: @waffles thank you for adding in the link to the message. That will be very helpful.

Comment: @Sathya one thing I noticed is that the grace period can mess stuff up a bit notification wise, but overcoming that is a huge PITA