# Pending approvals:Please add a “meaningless words not removed” rejection reason

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Often I see pending edits when the editor has not removed meaningless works like “thanks”, “please”, etc.  If the edit is only doing half job and is not even bothered to clean up this sort of simple problem, I tent to reject  (or improve) the edit.

There is no way to  inform the editor of what is wrong the edit in enough detail that  they start to do full job.

Comment: I believe "too minor" covers that.

Comment: Alternatively, allow for "Other" with free text as originally suggested in [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections). (And when allowing free text, also allow that for approvals, in case someone investigated and wants to pass that to the other reviewers.)

Comment: But, @Jeff, that does not make explicit *what* is wrong?

Comment: @Jeff, even if the change is a big change (so not too minor) we should not be aproving edits (and therefore reward rep) when the editor has not finshed the job.

Comment: "You missed a lot of sh*t" or "You suck at editing" or "do you have attention deficit hyperac ***OMG A SQUIRREL***"

Comment: @IanRingrose If you would reject an edit that finished the job as too minor, then the edit was good enough.

Answer (score 11):

> even if the change is a big change (so not too minor) we should not be aproving edits (and therefore reward rep) when the editor has not finshed the job.

I disagree entirely.  The point of editing is to improve the post.  If the post is substantially improved, the edit should be approved.  Keeping crap instead of good content in order to avoid giving someone a measly 2 rep is ridiculous.

There's an "improve" button if the edit isn't perfect and you want to further it.  This is exactly why it's there and there isn't just "approve" and "reject".

Comment: I'm conflicted on this. Substantial edits are good, but we also want to train editors to not leave the job half-finished when finishing would require practically zero additional effort. Actually, this reminds me a bit of the topic of [my recent question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107468/what-can-we-do-about-low-quality-edits).

Comment: I agree with Popular Demand. There should be a way to address editors (ie: a custom message to be attached regardless of whether a suggested edit is approved or rejected).

Comment: One option: Comment on the post (that way everyone who sees it learns).  `@editorname` works without them needing to comment.

Comment: @MatthewRead but if you want to do that, the edit has to get approved without anyone hitting "Improve" because if you improve then you are the editor.

Comment: @agf: I wonder if it would be hard to allow `@replies` to be addressed to the original editor of an improved edit. That could work as a lightweight alternative to my suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize it only worked for the last editor.  One could approve, comment, then improve ... kind of messy.

Answer (score 8):

If a user is making a good but incomplete edit, I do not think we should "punish" them by rejecting it. We want to encourage them to become better editors, not discourage them from editing at all.

So how about instead showing the original editor a message similar to the rejection message, when their edit was *improved*? They could then click through to the improved edit, notice that your improvement also removed the "Thanks", and learn it that way.

There could also be an "improvement reason/message", where you can explain to the original editor why you think it had to be improved.

That way, you can still teach them how to improve their editing, without rejecting an edit that, while incomplete, still improved the quality of the original post.

I think constructive feedback is a better teaching mechanism than just a plain "no, not good enough!".

Comment: This could be a good idea.

Comment: This would be a lot more coding for the SE team, but I like it...