# Bug in edit history associated with initial answer phase (non-recorded)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, edits, revisions-list

I am referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553504/451969). The initial answer had some tab-delimited code that was quite messy looking, as well as a Google link to search results associated with MDN. I waited what I thought was a few minutes, and considered posting a comment along the lines of "Please don't link to Google search results". I figured (wrongly) the answerer was no longer working on the answer.

So I edited it, reformatting the code, adding `()` to `.call()` to inline functions, etc., and very lightly edited the word choice (to remove personal pronouns). Note, I did **not** make any substantial edits, such as changing functions or anything.

Yet, see the edit associated with my account here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8553504/revisions.

All I can say is that that is *not* right. Also, if you look at the history, there is no unformatted code or Google link anymore at all. Somehow my edit got blended with a version that is no longer available, which distorts what my edit actually was in reality.

Is this a bug? Shouldn't the "This has been edited by someone else" notice shown up? Shouldn't the edit history kick in once someone *else* has edited the answer, including the most previous version (that the first third-party answer was based on)?

**EDIT** - I added **Feature Request** as a tag in relation to the *logging to revisions any changes made by third party and keep the most previous revision*. I can't tell if this is how it is currently, but I think it makes sense (I certainly thought this was the case).

Comment: Note, when stackoverflow makes mistakes like this, people can start shouting at each other for things they havn't done. It's a bug the encourages conflict since the edit history suggest question/answer sabotage.

Comment: agree with @Raynos, after I fixed the most urgent issues with the post, I waited some 1-2min, refreshed and saw the new "bomb" edit and the history didn't reflect this at all.

Comment: @Esailija - The last edit I saw before I left the page (before Raynos made his comment to me notifying me of a problem) was one where you added the jQuery source text reference at the top of the first code block, that one line. I assumed I had done you a small favor formatting the code (which can be a pain) and didn't expect there to be any issue. Yet, that edit is not in the revision history.

Comment: Related (or a duplicate?): [Inline editing silently overwrites other people's changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106872/inline-editing-silently-overwrites-other-peoples-changes). (See also the link to [the implementation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247) in waffles' answer there.)

Comment: @Arjan - Is the answer editor considered the *inline editor*?

Comment: @Arjan - Also, I would claim that my actual edit wasn't substantive, that it wasn't substantive without all of the other changes I didn't make. But I'm not an educated on how the diff algorithm works. (Although, I did replace a few tabs with a lot of spaces.)

Comment: Whenever clicking "edit" does not get you a new page with only *that* specific post to edit (so, if the editor opens up in the current page itself, still showing all other posts, comments, et cetera) then you're using the "inline editor".

Comment: @Arjan - Ok, thank you. Is it possible all of the edits, including ones that occurred but aren't in the revision history, have been logged somewhere?

Comment: Waffles writes about [the implementation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247): *"If your edit is bigger than the previous edit by a certain margin it will be let through, when it overrides silently we log."* So maybe waffles can peek in that log to tell if that is indeed what happened here.

Comment: @Arjan - I'd certainly be interested, but from reading his (her?) posts, it seems like he's a developer. I don't want to impose, but if they end up looking at this closer, I'd very much like to see the logs.

Comment: Yes, waffles is a SE employee, err, [Valued Associate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00008/) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan or was. :-)