# OP's edits being incorrectly merged into my revision?

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

I tried to tidy up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16372871/472495) earlier, and later noticed that a chunk of text had been deleted that I didn't intend to remove (see [revision 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16372871/revisions)).

I edited that back in revision 4, thinking I had just been a bit clumsy, and then noticed that in rev 2 the code had also been amended (all the comments have been prefixed with "We", and a new chunk was added on the end). That *categorically* was not me, but it has been attributed to my username.

Buglet?

Comment: Probably a clash with an edit by the OP in the grace period. OP added "we", saved after you started editing, you saved after OP.

Comment: The edit system should however correctly attribute who has done what, otherwise people will be held responsible for edits they did not make. Clearly some deliberate edit merging is going on, otherwise my edit would have removed the code edits (either they would not have shown up, or would be attributed to the OP and then removed by my later edit).

Comment: Related: [the rules of silently overwriting other edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win/93247#93247) (but which, of course, should not be presented in the edit history the way it does).

Comment: Hmmm, my question sounds like [a dup of this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116404/bug-in-edit-history-associated-with-initial-answer-phase-non-recorded). However that is around a year and a half old, for what sounds like a serious bug. Tell me it's not the same thing? `;-)`.