# Two simultaneous edits voided one of the edits (bug or reverted by OP?)

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline editing silently overwrites other people's changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106872/inline-editing-silently-overwrites-other-peoples-changes)

I can't see any other mention of this exact problem here on Meta Stack Overflow.

The [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8780507/revisions) I made were reverted, and it looks like it could be a bug.
Why could it be a bug?

- There's no real reason to revert the changes I made.
- Both edits occurred simultaneously.

Why should not have it been simply reverted? I used the phrase 'formatting and wordiness' in the edit comment and may have frustrated the user.

What's the best way to deal with this if it is a user reverting comments?

- Flag for Moderator? +1
- Comment on the user post?

Comment: The OP is almost certainly unaware that he stepped over your edits. I usually reapply my edits, including in them the additional changes the OP has made.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetrotta for editing it. And if a user was reverting it? Best to flag for a Mod and explain?

Comment: Actually, it was the... [other Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/users/309308/michael-mrozek)... who edited it.

Comment: Oh, right. Might has well been, I'm a Michael as well...so Michael's got it, either way ;-)