# Edit behaviour: Yellow line at top is missing (indicating that someone else already edited)

Tags: feature-request, support, edits

It happened sometimes or since some time, that I can start my edit, but someone else was faster and sent his edit already (into queue e.g.). 
I found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106565/indicator-of-an-ongoing-edit) , that describes the feature I expected and got sometimes.

**What circumstances avoid that this line shows up?** My problem arises when I don't see this nice yellow hint, press "Save Edit" and got an 404 error page.

Might the yellow one only appears if the edit is done by a 2k+ rep user and the yellow line can't appear immadietly when a 2k- user like me did this edit because it needs to be peer reviewed?

Edit: Because when I go back to the question itself I see clear that the edit-link [has gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link), which is indicating that an edit is awaiting in queue to be peer reviewed.

For technical question: using Opera 11.62 with JS on.

Update: Is this the page that should appear? Igot this message last time, but sometimes later I got a (*"our queue for suggested edits is full"*):
[image]

Comment: Unless something changed with the recent WebSockets upgrade, the rule is that questions only poll to see if there are others every 45 (?) seconds or so. I'm surprised you're getting a 404 and not some other error, though... are you sure you're not talking about a deleted post?

Comment: @PopularDemand Yes, I'm very sure that I'm talking about a 404 and the post was still there but edited. I wrote it directly after editing a question when it happened, because it annoyed me again. Next time I might take a screenshot.