# Vanished edit for tag-wiki, how can I see what happend?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Yesterday, I added an overview-link for [iso-prolog](/questions/tagged/iso-prolog). I saw it "in the queue" with the remark that the edit will be only visible when it has been reviewed.

Today I no longer see anything related to my edit yesterday.

So has my edit been rejected? I cannot see anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been rejected. Go to your [Activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to find the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1062313

Comment: Thank you. So there was no notification I missed?

Comment: @false No, you don't get notified for approved* / rejected suggestions. (`*` you might see +2 reputation if the edit is approved)

Comment: @false feature request for notifications like you'd expect is probably this one: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: @gnat: Thank you, seems again that actual contributions are discouraged ; while click-through reviews are encouraged but sneered at (in one of the last podcasts). So SO is selecting a unique breed of reviewers.

Comment: @false that's sad indeed. As far as I can tell the motivation behind _silent edit rejections_ looks nice at the first sight but becomes rather slippery [in mote thorough analysis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136479/165773). BTW they also say [SO is working on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151778/165773) what you call _selecting a unique breed of reviewers_... one can only hope the work is over before [thoughtful reviewers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) all run away :(

Comment: @gnat: I listened to a/the last podcast: They discussed how to demean "serial accepters" by finding some name for them like "robovoters" or the like. Instead of realizing that people go for low-hanging fruits, in particular in a system were some fruits do hang too low. The meta-feedback loop for such items is not the best. But to be fair, a lot of things **do** work perfectly here!