# Review limit increment in base of review quality

Tags: feature-request, review, limits

Should the review queue limit increment if the review quality is higher?

Comment: High rep != great reviewer.

Comment: I said probably. Honestly I think that a lot of user doesn't has enough interest in reviewing

Comment: But yes we can (may be) increase review limit by review quality (i.e. review audit)

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: The system can't really measure review *quality*, and I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users who spend a lot of time reviewing don't receive reputation for it (indeed it takes away time from earning rep), so using it as an indicator of reviewing competence is a tenuous association at best.*

As hims056 has pointed out, a better indicator would be number of review audits passed, but this is also problematic, since it is entirely possible to never have had an audit. Audits are also not a very good indicator of something as abstract as review quality; they're just there to catch [cases of outright abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits). As long as you're paying a moderate amount of attention, you can pass all audits and still be a terrible reviewer.

The current daily quota is sufficient for anyone who wants do their part and help out in the review queues. Short of badge hunting, there is no reason to go on extended reviewing sprees.

* *Question originally suggested giving higher reputation users more reviews*