# Can we distinguish between "edit was already approved" and "edit has been improved?"

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I am on record as frustrated by robo approvers. However I continue to work the queues partly because I don't want them to "win". As I explained in [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits) it is very disheartening to see

> This edit was already approved, please visit the post blah blah blah

Generally, I visit the post. And about 10% of the time, I discover that whatever was ticking me off (adding Thanks to a post that didn't have it, fixing the capitalization of Thanks while not formatting the code, adding random backticks around words to highlight them - just to choose today's issues) has been fixed. The edit isn't pending any more, but it's not so much because the crap that was shown to me has been approved, but rather that some generous soul has clicked Improve (which I do as well, on my better days) and fixed up the post. *Aaaah. That feels nice*.

It would help my mood a lot if "this edit was already approved" could read "this edit was already improved" when that is what has happened. Is it technically feasible?

Comment: It would be pleasing on the eye wouldn't it :-); but only if the improver has unchecked the suggested edit was helpful box...

Comment: Oh it would be cooler still to get "approved and improved" or "rejected and improved" depending on the state of that box. But even if they left it checked, I'd like to know it's been improved post approval.