# Allow "wait for an item to review"

Tags: feature-request, review

I want to help review.  When I go to the review page, and it says there are some items queued for review, it seems like 90% of the time when I click a review category, I'm told "The queue has been cleared!"  I keep going back to the Reviews page, seeing there's something to review, but then ending up unable to review anything.  It's very frustrating!

It seems to me that the top-level Review page is accurately telling me there are items queued, *at the time the page was rendered*, but then I guess other people are beating me to the punch on those queued items.

And it seems to me that there are so very many items coming into the queues (at least for, say, First Posts), that it warrants the following suggestion:

On the "queue has been cleared" page, have an option to "wait for another item to be queued," whereby I can sit back and wait for an item to be assigned to me, rather than having to manually go back and forth between the top-level Review page and a category page until I get lucky.  If an item is assigned to me and I don't review it in, say, 2 minutes, then take it back away from me and re-queue it.

Comment: I think of this every time I go to the reviews queue

Comment: At least on SO, the opposite is also very common. If it says that the queue is empty, you can click on it, and often get reviews.

Answer (score 7):

> On the "queue has been cleared" page, have an option to "wait for
>   another item to be queued," whereby I can sit back and wait for an
>   item to be assigned to me

While this seems nice, it will not work.

For example, lets say a site has 100 people who do reviews regularly at around the same time each night. Now, lets say the Late Answers queue normally only gets about 20 reviews total during this time period, and you have 40 people that are *waiting* for a review in this queue. You are only likely going to get 0 or 1 reviews to do. And you're going to have to stay on this page, waiting. They would need to likely implement a buzzer sound to let you know when a review is ready, or else you probably won't notice you have one. Thus it will just take longer for reviews to get reviewed.

Also, I think the problem you mentioned, is only really a problem on [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266078/3041194). Since the real-time updating of the review numbers on the `/review` page was becoming way to resource intensive. Thus they changed it to how it is now, where it is inconvenient many times, since no review for you when you click, even though it shows.

So a better feature request, I think, would be for it to go back how it was, not make an unnecessary waiting system. This is the internet, we don't like to wait.

Comment: Or we could, yknow, make more stuff to review

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of the review queues is to help people willing to spend time improving the quality of the site's content find things for them to do.  There is *always* something that you could be doing to improve the site's content.  If the queues aren't able to give you anything to work on then that is a failure of the queue's job of helping you find work that you can do.

Rather than having SE spend time trying to notify you of when it eventually comes up with work to do, their time would be better spent improving the ability of the queues to find work for you.  This could mean adjusting the existing queues to feed in additional types of work when they are empty, or it could mean adding new queues to handle entirely different problems not addressed by the existing queues (there are all sorts of possibilities here).

If you don't want to wait for SE to fix the problem, you can handle it on your own as well.  There are [all sorts of options available to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155573/186381) for finding ways to improve the site content outside of the review system.  If the queues aren't helping you find things to fix, find them on your own.

Answer (score 2):

> On the "queue has been cleared" page, have an option to "wait for another item to be queued," whereby I can sit back and wait for an item to be assigned to me

I agree with the idea that a notification may be useful for users who are willing to help in reviewing, but I also agree with cVplZ that the proposed assignment of reviews to users will not work ( for the reasons he mentioned in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244489/245167))

A possible alternate solution could be to enable an indicator in the top bar whenever there is any item available in the queue, so that interested users can go and review, if they want to.

At present, there is an orange indicator visible in the top bar if there are suggested edits waiting for review. Out of the two sites where I have the privilege to review edits, Stack Overflow shows the indicator when there are 15+ items in the queue, and MSE shows the indicator if there is any item available in the review queue. I find these indicators for the Suggested Edits queue very useful, and I think a similar indicator may be useful for those who wish to be notified when there are items available for review in the other queues.