# How is a more substantive edit less substantive?

Tags: support, edits

Both Blazemonger and myself edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14507790/revisions) at roughly the same time. My edit couldn't be saved as it was less substantive than Blazemonger's.

I changed absolutely everything that Blazemonger did; and then "a lot" more. Why was my edit unable to be saved because it was less substantive?

Is there a definition of substantive?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93247/89334 suggests 25 more characters edited is the barrier.

Comment: I don't think it is "More substantive than the earlier edit", rather "More substantive than you have currently done, disregarding the similar edits". So you were not dismissed because it was somehow less of an edit than Blazemonger's.

Comment: I guess that answers the question @waiwai933 though a up-to-date answer would be great (and there was no way of finding that question so this might act as a better pointer to it).