# Don't raise an edit conflict over tags

Tags: feature-request, edits

If someone edits the tags of a question and someone else edits both the body and the tags, the latter edit can't go through and suggests refreshing.

Can a notice perhaps be shown instead, and the edits merged?

Comment: Isn't this a [bug]? More substantial edits [are always supposed to win](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93235/).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Huh, I suppose so. The message did say "the tags on this question have already been edited", though, so I figured it was somehow the intended behaviour.