# We need diff/merge tools for conflicting edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, concurrency

I came accross this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095549/compute-the-percentage-top-padding-based-on-the-height-of-the-parent-instead-o#24095549 (**removed, 10k+ rep needed**)

It was quite unreadable but after 5-10 minutes I figured out what the guy meant. So I went on to make edits, pretty much reformatting the entire post. After 5 minutes of work I had something much better, but I couldn't save it because the OP had made some edits in the meantime of just a few characters.

So I clicked `click here to load` and all of my edits were gone. I got back what looked like the original post.

As you can understand I felt a bit upset for doing 5 minutes of voluntary work that had to be thrown in the bin, worst of all **without warning!** The system needs to improve on this in my opinion. At the very least **warn** that I should copy my changes and paste them after loading.

I would suggest implementing the warning in the meantime while searching for even better solutions. Ideally, give us something that works like SVN, merge additions automatically and let the editor merge conflicts.

Comment: It is a frustration experienced by all of us now and then. Think about providing an answer for 30 minutes to find the post gone... to fix this we would need something different then [optimistic concurency](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22135/optimistic-concurrency-for-post-edits)...

Comment: Now you know. Copy your changes before reloading and manually diff the changes. There isn't a silver-bullet solution to this (but some diff utilities would be nice).

Comment: Perhaps "Click to load" should say "Click to throw away all of your edits", if you've made edits.

Comment: Compromise until such thing is implemented, if at all, can be saving a draft of the latest edit - one draft per site that will save your last edit on the server side and when you come back to edit the same post it will show you the draft.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good idea, but then it would have to appear also after you've loaded the conflicting edits (not only after you reload the page or "come back").

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester well, yes - it will show the last edit you wrote, as soon as you click the "edit" link.