# Allow the <small> tag

Tags: feature-request, markdown, design

Can the `<small>` HTML tag be allowed and properly styled?

Currently people wanting to write something small use either <sup>sup</sup> or <sub>sub</sub> which achieves a similar effect, but using it for small text is:

- Semantically wrong
- Too small
- Only the most advanced users know of this "feature"

---

Small text is very useful in many circumstances on most (if not all) stack exchange websites. Here is a couple use cases! I put the text that would be `<small>` in *italics* instead.

- **Stack Overflow**: If your C++ class has a private variable you cannot access it outside of the class or outside of friend classes/functions, that's the whole point of it!

  *Note: if you really want to you can access it using pointer hacks, but the method to do that varies from compiler to compiler and it's technically undefined behavior.*
- **Super User**: If your computer doesn't boot try the following step: [...]

  *Since you mentioned being an advanced user I skipped the most obvious reasons, such as the computer not being plugged in. But it never hurts to double check!*

Comment: related but not a dup (unless a question can be a dupe of an answer): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26756/how-do-i-use-a-small-font-size-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: RobW commented [on an answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag/75926#comment350478_75926), referring to [the new specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/small.html) of `<small>`. It's now referring to “the fine print” or “the small print”. [That's even worse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_print), if I understand correctly.

Comment: Eh, I think notes or asides are very useful, if handled correctly buy the author. They help users skim the most important information, and pass over small explanatory notes (or sometimes snarky comments).

Comment: I agree notes can be useful, @Rob (except for snarky comments, which could be removed instead). But I doubt `<small>` is the best option. Earlier that was about presentation, not content. And today it seems the HTML5 recommendation refers to [the Wikipedia definition of small print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_print). If true, then using it doesn't feel right to me either. (Though of course it's NOT likely that some browsers/readers would suddenly add/speak some "Warning, alert, beware" for `<small`>, nor that company firewalls would block pages that use it...)

Comment: That wikipedia article is odd, focusing on only the negative aspects of small print. From [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/): *"<small> is now for side comments, which are the inline equivalent of <aside> — content which is not the main focus of the page."* Side comments aren't inherently negative, whether they're legal or explanatory. There are plenty of S.O. users who use various tricks to size some text small to show that it's a side comment -- might as well give them a semantic element to do it with.

Comment: Smaller text is *harder to read* (and it's not the only way to denote secondary content).

Comment: @MadScientist, see also [Add explicit support for citing scientific literature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116397/add-explicit-support-for-citing-scientific-literature), though surely I'd like something more generic.

Comment: @Arjan I'm aware of that feature request as I wrote it myself ;-)

Comment: I don't agree that sub is too small, but otherwise - +1 for sure.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Actually, I use `<sup>` *and* `<sub>` to get the small text effect <sup><sub>that I love so dearly</sub></sup>.

But real, honest-to-goodness `<small>` support would be nicer. For one thing, <sub><sup>this is actually</sup></sub> <sup><sub>a bit *too* small...</sub></sup>

Comment: +1 for the nice trick to get small with sup+sup

Comment: Something that I find interesting, it only seems to work if the `<sub>` is inside of `<sup>`

Comment: nice trick, although it looks like `<sub><sup>` makes the text closer to the baseline that `<sup><sub>`. at least on firefox.

Comment: @Kip: this is true.

Comment: There’s a related argument for allowing `<smallcaps>` to get the CSS `font-variant: small-caps;` to trigger. It’s much more readable (and portable) when the CSS is used instead of something that emulates it, like subscripting capitals. The x-height of small caps is the same as that of the font itself, which in the case of super/subscript is not even true.

Comment: @Shog9, You can combine `<sub><sup>` with `<h1>`, `<h2>` etc to get a *bigger* small size.

Comment: Nearly six years later without activity, do you think maybe please we could finally have `<small>` instead o fugly hacks that don't work so well?

Comment: `<sub><sub><sub><sup><sup><sup>It's the smallest one!</sup></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub>`

Answer (score 26):

If you can make it bigger

## which

### you

#### certainly

can

(to a degree)

then you certainly should

<sub>be allowed</sub>

<sub><sub>to make it smaller</sub></sub>

<sub><sub><sub>without resorting to semantically incorrect tagging and incorrect baselining!</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: More precisely: you're not able to make it bigger, you're able to use headers and such. Some day, or when accessed differently (screen readers, mobile, data dump, API), headings might be rendered totally different. Likewise, a `<small>` tag has little to do with content.

Comment: @Arjan: Not so. Behold the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/small.html

Comment: Aha, you're right @RobW: *"Although previous versions of HTML defined the small element only in presentational terms, the element has now been given the specific semantic purpose of representing those parts of documents that are often referred to as “the fine print” or “the small print”."* Also: some time ago these sites switched to using HTML5. But still then: should we encourage [using fine print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_print)?

Comment: The unbroken link of @RobW's comment: [w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/small](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/small). Or was it [w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element)

Answer (score 22):

I sometimes abuse<sup>†</sup> `<sup>` for the text of footnotes, which is not really needed for any other reason than to make a too long of an answer look shorter.

Hence, I'd prefer [some Markdown's footnotes extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes) over `<small>`, especially as the semantics of a footnote could (one day) allow for different rendering (like tooltips, or like including links to jump back to where the footnote was referenced, Wikipedia-style, for very long answers...).

<sup>†</sup> Of course, using `<sup>` for the footnote *mark* is not abusive, but for footnote *text* it is.

Comment: I'd just come to the conclusion that `<small>` doesn't seem to fix the issue of being _semantically_ wrong (since `<small>` is a visual concept, not a semantic one) and that something along the lines of "note" or "footnote" would suit the examples much better... when I saw this answer! +1

Comment: semantically <small> is used for smallprint, not small as in size.

Comment: Adding proper Markdown footnote support as in CommonMark would be the ideal. On other sites (Discourse-based), I can get by with `&sup1;`, a line break `***`, `##### Notes` and actual notes inside `<small></small>`. It works but it's complicated and unnecessary. Footnotes are a courtesy to shorten text to its essential aspect while providing relevant background information for those who need or want in-depth knowledge.

Answer (score 16):

One use case for the `<small>` tag would be bibliographies at the bottom of posts for the scientific sites on the network. The references shouldn't dominate the post, so making the text for them a bit smaller is quite useful.

Using the `<sup>` tag as a hack to make text smaller has other problems as it does affect more than the font size. It's interactions with numbered or unordered lists is problematic at best, and it leads to strange line spacing in some instances. It also needs to be applied on a per paragraph base, not just around a whole list of references, which is more work.

As for balphas concern that the tag would be misused, we already have the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags and they are widely known, so anyone inclined to misuse small text is probably already doing it.

An example bibliography hacked together with `<sup>` tags follows

---

- <sup>[Dall’Olio, G. M. et al. Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities. *PLoS Comput Biol* **7**, (2011).](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002202)</sup>
- <sup>[Watson, J. D. & Crick, F. H. C. Molecular Structure of Nucleic Acids: A Structure for Deoxyribose Nucleic Acid. *Science* **171**, 737-738 (1953).](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/171737a0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `<sup>` and `<sub>` do not achieve the same effect, they are small but positioned different vertically as your post has rightly demonstrated.

I'm curious what would you need a small text for? Fine prints, disclaimers, foot notes? I don't see why these can't be displayed as normal sized text.

In anycase, I totally agree that using `sup`/`sub` for the sole purpose of making the text smaller is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Well, it's already used a lot.. See for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/show-the-diff-between-two-non-consecutive-revisions-of-a-post

Comment: Yes, I've seen many cases like that. I am totally fine with the "PS" line in normal size. I do that all the time. If your proposal is to allow `small` tag so people who insist on having smaller text will then use a semantically correct tag, I agree. Though I would rather they don't do it at all. :)

Comment: @o.k.w: You certainly *can* display everything in the same font size. Heck, I made do with a single font size for *years*... But then my old Smith Corona wore out and I moved on. Font sizes are nice when you want to emphasize something (headings) or de-emphasize something (foot notes, disclaimers, things that most readers won't care about but which need to be included for the sake of completeness).

Comment: smaller fonts for footnotes and disclaimers have been standard in print for a long time. (centuries probably.) it signals to the reader "hey, this is more boring than the main text, you don't need to read it unless you really care".

Comment: With that reasoning we don't **need** big text either, or formatting of any kind.

Comment: I edited my question to provide use cases.

Answer (score -9):

I disagree. The only thing this is really used for is tongue-in-cheek emulation of the proverbial fine print, usually for something off-topic. That's okay on Meta, but discouraged on SO*, and it's used a lot less there. Allowing the "canonical" tag `<small>`, I fear, would lead to many more people being smart about the layout of the site. *Shudder.*

<sub>*Do you know SO? That's a great website, and I have even less rep there than here!</sub>

Comment: I edited my question to provide some use cases. Are you still against this?

Comment: I usually use `<sub>` at the bottom of blockquotes for attribution...

Comment: Is there a chance to revisit this decision? The `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags exist already an can be abused in this way, I don't think a `<small>` tag would be any more prone to abuse. I've added some arguments why the `<sub>` and `<sup>` are not ideal and a `<small>` tag is needed in my answer to this question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123393/151385).