# Trailing spaces on comment link format

Tags: discussion, comments

Trailing spaces on comment link format preventing it to form a link

```
[Stack Overflow ](http://stackoverflow.com)
```

May be by-design or even dup, but just reporting what I accidentally found today.

Comment: This is `bydesign` per [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79145/why-is-mini-markdown-working-in-some-of-my-comments-but-broken-in-others/79146#79146), but I feel like there's a more specific duplicate somewhere. Don't seem to be able to find it right now, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's by design because of tricksters who wish to subvert the minimum character comment input.

Comment: Can you elaborate how trailing spaces in link label subvert the minimum character comment input and why can't it be solved in a way that does not break such links, please?

Comment: Strange, there seem to be two checks. If there are less than 15 characters, the comment can not be submitted. Both the ENTER key and the "Add Comment" button do nothing. If there are a few characters and then enough spaces to makes total over 15, submit works, but it just triggers a popup saying: Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.