# The link in the comment from marking as duplicate breaks on trailing whitespace

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto “possible duplicate” comment should use trimmed title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103627/auto-possible-duplicate-comment-should-use-trimmed-title)

When marking [At what time will the upcoming Ubuntu release be made available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65476/6969) as duplicate of [On what specific time are ubuntu versions made public?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37315/6969), the next comment was generated:

```
possible duplicate of [On what time on April 28 is 11.04 released? ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37315/on-what-time-on-april-28-is-11-04-released)
```

However, due to the trailing space on the question's title, the code was not properly converted to a link and was displayed as:

> possible duplicate of [On what time on April 28 is 11.04 released? ]([On what specific time are ubuntu versions made public?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37315/on-what-time-on-april-28-is-11-04-released))

This bug can be solved in two ways:

- strip trailing whitespace from the question
- allow trailing whitespace in the description of such a link (related: [Trailing spaces on comment link format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94080/150311))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just voted to close [What reputation is needed to vote to migrate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149940/what-reputation-is-needed-to-vote-to-migrate/149941#149941) as an exact duplicate.

The automated comment inserted was:

```
possible duplicate of [What is a "closed" question?  ]
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)
```

The trailing spaces after *"question?"* causes the link to break.

[Bo Persson's edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10582/revisions) appears to have fixed the issue, there was trailing whitespace in the title so the fix is to automagically remove trailing spaces in the title as happens everywhere else.

i.e. BUMP

Comment: Thanks, this case will be fixed in the next build.