# What reputation is needed to vote to migrate?

Tags: support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

I can see in the list of privileges how much reputation is needed to vote to close a question — I am very far away. But what do I need to vote to *migrate* a question, and does it make any difference if it was me asking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vote to migrate is a vote to close. Therefore you need the same reputation.

If you don't have enough reputation you can flag it for moderator attention. Use the "Off Topic" reason and select the site you believe it should be migrated to.

Answer (score 1):

You require 3000 reputation to [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions). In beta sites you require 500 reputation to [gain these privileges](https://chess.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: 500 on Beta sites.