# Link is not formed if here is a space in the front of the description on comments

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

[A working link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf) is obtained by as usual;

`[A working link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf)`

If we insert space in the front of the description it will work on work question and answer text

[A working link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf)

But it will not work on the comments.

`[ A working link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf)`

This is bad since we usually copy some text that may include a front space. It should be the same as the question and answer body.

Comment: **Sample here:** [ A non working link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf) and try yourself

Comment: Well, if MathJax is enabled it is easy bypass the minimum `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$` as considered as a [design point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94805/403350)