# Link in comments occasionally not formatted on MathJax-enabled site

Tags: bug, status-review, comments, hyperlinks, mathjax

Occasionally, links in comments that use MathJax do not show normally. The problem is reproducible, and browser-agnostic. It comes and goes depending on inserting a space around the closing `$` characters of a MathJax expression before or after the link. It occurs for

```
Alice $u $ Bob [link](https://stackexchange.com) Carol $v$ David.
```

I setup a demo on [an abandoned question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18065/555) at crypto-SE. The rest of the present question is a picture taken from that page.

[image: fubar]

Comment: So you fail to use propper formatting, and now complain that impropper formatting doesn't render correctly? Example 1 and 3 work because they are consistant, which fails for 2 and 4.

Comment: @Luuklag: per what spec is having a space at the end of a MathJax expression improper?

Comment: Related: *[Trailing spaces on comment link format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94080/trailing-spaces-on-comment-link-format)* and *[Why is mini-markdown working in some of my comments, but broken in others?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79145/)*. A comment to the latter has (my emphasis): *"Note it seems the leading/trailing spaces checks also* ***apply to names with MathJax text"***