# Why not remove trailing spaces after a question title? 

Tags: bug, status-completed, title

I note that if there is a space after the question title, it is not removed and left as such. There is at least one issue with leaving the space right there. It breaks the *possible dupe* comment markdown. [Really](https://askubuntu.com/posts/65911/revisions).

While I agree that one can simply fix this by editing the question title or the comment to fix the broken markdown, we should strive to do it the programmatic way. Just to follow Joel Spolsky's ideology.

I believe if the [trailing exclamation marks can be converted into a question mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/stop-rewriting-trailing-exclamation-marks-as-question-marks), similarly, removing the trailing space should be possible as well.

---

I realize that if there is space after the title when you initially ask a question, it is removed. But, subsequently if it was edited in (like I just did), it is not removed.

*Hence marking it as a bug instead of feature request.*

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79145/why-is-mini-markdown-working-in-some-of-my-comments-but-broken-in-others/79146#79146) seems similar but apparently, it wasn't fixed properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been the case for a long time (since, as you found, February of 2011), but it only happened on *submission* of the question, not on subsequent *edits* (in the example you found, the spaces where added in a later edit to the title). That's fixed in the next build.

Also, the trailing/leading spaces [no longer break](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103627/auto-possible-duplicate-comment-should-use-trimmed-title/149971#149971) the comments, so even for older questions, that wouldn't be an issue anymore.