# Buggy comment of Possible Duplicate

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-inserted “possible duplicate” comment does not trim whitespace from question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130963/auto-inserted-possible-duplicate-comment-does-not-trim-whitespace-from-questio)

I just [reported a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161013/opencv-haar-classifier-threshold) as possible duplicate, and the comment automatically added by the system seems to have format problems:

[image]

Comment: Might it be due to the trailing space in the title?

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't those be removed automatically when the user enters a title?

Comment: See also [Trailing space in question title breaks the possible-duplicate autocomment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132725/trailing-space-in-question-title-breaks-the-possible-duplicate-autocomment) and [Why not remove trailing spaces after a question title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132705/why-not-remove-trailing-spaces-after-a-question-title)