# What happens when two editors edit the same post?

Tags: support, edits, concurrency

Of course one of the two editors *A* will get her edit stored before the other one *B*.

But what happens to the resulting post that appears on the page without clicking the `edit` buttons?

- Show only the latest *B* edition, *A* one is lost in space until the next big bang?
- Show the *B* one (kenobi) but the *A* one will appear in the edition stack?
- The system does have a subtle algorithm that detects that the 2nd edit was started while the 1st one was not stored yet, and either displays a kind of warning to the editor or to the member viewer?

Comment: How is this a feature-request?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/show-the-diff-between-two-non-consecutive-revisions-of-a-post

Comment: @Lazer if you read the post, and the 3rd item, you will understand that a feature could be added.

Comment: @ring0 - the system already does that. Not sure of the time interval required for it to trigger, but it does warn you if you are still editing when someone else has already saved and edit.

Comment: (Things have changed in March 2011; see the edits below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts (as a class) can be broken down into components such as body, title, and tags.

The system allows revisions to be merged, but only on different components. I.e., if a component is unchanged from the last revision, that component is eligible for merging. Changes to the same component get overwritten by the second edit.

As an example, [see revisions 4 and 5 here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4297600/revisions) (10k only, see screenshot below -- click for full size) -- notice how the first sentence of the post body was reverted to what it was before I made revision 4, but my edits to the title remained the same. <sub><sup>(I swear I didn't do this just to make an example for this question! lol)</sup></sub>

[image]

---

There is already a [warning system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts) in place to alert users that a post has been changed while the user is editing, although in practice it's not 100% reliable to deliver the notification (and, it can always be ignored).

Since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119), if a conflict occurs.

Answer (score 1):

When an editor saves his changes, a new revision is created in the edit history. The newest revision is the one displayed by default. When somebody started editing doesn't matter, it only matters when they submit their changes.

<s>There are no warnings or other indications that some other revision was "overwritten" by an edit. You can only find out by checking the edit history.</s>

Since March 2011, a warning is shown [after you save](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119), if a conflict occurs.

While you are still editing, you might already get a notification bar pop-up that tells you about other edits that occurred since you started your edit.