# Edit suggestion out of sync

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

There was once an edit suggestion from a low-rep user.  It was actually a retag, adding a new one.

https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/2885

However, a 10k user some time after, retagged the question exactly the same adding the same tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4918977/revisions

At the time, it was shown that there was still a pending edit (though I think the `(0)` was next to the `retag` button).  I attempted to accept it but it wouldn't let me saying something along the lines of: "cannot accept, this edit has been already made."  However, the suggestion didn't go away, it was still shown as pending.  Multiple attempts to accept didn't work.  So I figured it'd be best to just reject it since the edit was already made.  The rejection went through, the pending suggestion disappeared and I am credited for the rejection.

Is this the intended behavior?

---

I would have thought that if a 10k makes an edit, it overrides all pending suggestions and clears the queue.  If not all, suggestions of the same type (pending retag overridden and removed by a 10k retag) or same changes (though I imagine this would be difficult/expensive to detect).  Also if the system wouldn't allow me to accept it, why would it let me reject it?  It shouldn't go on my "permanent record" that I "rejected" this suggestion, I preferred to have accepted it.

The timestamps are:

```
retag suggestion:  2011-02-07 07:54:39Z  (taken from the suggestion page)  
10k retag:         2011-02-07 08:17:52Z  (taken from the revisions page)  
my rejection:      2011-02-07 08:26:03Z  (taken from my profile page)
```

Side note: If this is indeed a bug and not the intended behavior, could this rejection be removed from my history?  I don't consider this a real rejection, I would have accepted this one had I been given the chance.

Comment: Just as an aside, for those wondering why things might be difficult: [apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71089/what-happens-when-two-editors-edit-the-same-post/71107#71107) the title, body and tags are kind of standalone edits, which if applicable can be merged automatically if two people edit simultaneously. Nice! Though apparently it can cause some problems, if the above is related to this. (I guess the inline tag-editing causes this, as normally 10k's wont be able to click the "edit" link without getting to the peer review when there are pending edits?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question and very thorough research!

It was an oversight on our part that we did not disable inline tag editing when a pending edit exists on a question.

A fix has been checked in and will be deployed today.

Comment: Sounds like good news.  Any possibility on reverting that rejection to an accept or removing it completely?