# Need moderator attention on SO right now

Tags: support, specific-question, abuse, rollbacks

It's a joke that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920280/how-do-i-set-custom-headers-in-ajax-closed) has not been deleted yet. Hoping to wake up a moderator by posting here.

And he just posted a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920535/bomb-amarica-bomb-amaricabomb-amarica), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920738/bomb-amarica-oh-yaaaaa-closed), and [yet one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920872/how-to-know-if-an-associative-array-contains-a-particular-value), [possible one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920945/how-to-find-out-if-an-associative-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: Holy revision war batman. They've rate limited all the useful tools, why not rate-limit 'rollback' for the OP and everyone else now too?

Comment: @George Stocker, couldn't agree more.

Comment: @George: Or prevent all kinds of edit conflicts with [at most one edit per 5 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/preventing-conflicting-simultaneous-edits/46118#46118).

Comment: @George - you should post that as a `feature-request`

Comment: I also think that 5 10K mods should be able to delete a question even though it's not 2 days old. I mean, it took over 30 mins for his first offensive/spam question to be deleted. It would have taken 30 seconds if we could have voted on deletion.

Comment: @klausbyskov: That's what spam flags are for.  If six people flag the question as spam, it gets deleted automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't feed trolls like this one.  Stop responding to them in any way, period.

Flag for moderator attention (or post on meta).

Attention is what they want; it doesn't matter if that's positive or negative.  Even though you are trying to revert vandalism on the site, responding to them encourages and escalates so they work harder to get around bans and other countermeasures.

It may be difficult to leave "<your name> is a bastard" on the post even for 10 minutes, for example, but realize it will soon get deleted.  You can always come back to address it later, if it doesn't.  (We have better things to do with our time than click rollback every 42 seconds, anyway, right? :P)

Comment: It was flagged for moderator attention at about the time it was closed, maybe a bit before due to the users posting insulting comments and continuous rollbacks

Comment: @Yacoby: Whenever moderators respond within 24h, that's plenty fast for me on SO.  OTOH, I do sympathize with you; I'm just trying to present a way to deal with trolls that limits escalation and overall crap.  OTGH, if flags for moderator attention are reset on rollback like spam/offensive, that would be a bug, IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

I'm really surprised this didn't reach the offensive flag threshold and get auto-deleted, which I would expect for this kind of behavior.

That's what we need to think about here. Why *didn't* that happen?

(note that it was at -20 so any edits wouldn't push it to the front page; we don't allow highly negative posts to appear on the front page of the site)

Maybe The Cat is right, leaving the offensive text in would have accelerated this process, since the rollback cycle interferes with offensive flags. If there was nothing to roll back to..

Comment: I flagged it offensive after flagging for moderator attention but it didn't show up in the "flags" page. Only one spam flag showed up. I assumed it was due to the fact that I had flagged it for moderator attention first but I did check and I got the "You can only flag this offensive once" message when I tried to flag it again.

Comment: Same here. And I flagged several comments too.

Comment: Though I say leave the offensive text in for completely other reasons ("hey, they don't care if I insult them. now I'm bored, maybe I can troll reddit?"), gathering more spam flags is a "bonus"!

Comment: Maybe when you downvote a question that is already below a certain threshold you should get a popup that says "flag as offensive/spam?"

Comment: @Yacoby: Each rollback resets offensive/spam flags to what they were at for the previous version. Or something like that.

Comment: @The Cat Ouch. IMHO that is quite a design flaw. I think the flags should remain as people shouldn't flag a question that isn't offensive.