# Offensive Flags broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791708/fuck-u-bitchezzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz) as offensive due to the behaviour of the OP. I'm sure I can't be the only person to have done so. In the mod tools it says it only has 1 spam flag and zero offensive flags.

Where did my vote go?

**Edit:** Ah maybe it was the rollback of the question that cleared the flags. In that case shouldn't it also allow me to reflag it?

Comment: The link only points to the mod tools.

Comment: @Georg - Sorry wrong link. Fixed the link now (10k SO users)

Comment: That question was already flagged into the nirvana.

Comment: @Georg - Yes I realised after asking the question that it might have been the rollback that ended up clearing all the flags so it had to start gathering flags again from scratch. In which case I suggest that flags are cancelled properly so we can reflag it. Same user obviously intent on causing as much trouble as possible before banning here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791858/in-ruby-on-rails-when-a-before-filter-is-used-then-the-local-variables-need-t/3791860#3791860 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790116/using-clustered-covariance-matrix-in-predict-lm/3791872#3791872

Comment: So, is the lesson here "don't rollback offensive posts to remove offensive material?"  That would defy conventional wisdom...

Comment: Ouch, i mod-flagged him as well. The flag-clearing appears to be [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/what-does-rollback-do-to-a-question).

Comment: [Related situation with advice on how to avoid an edit war](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51400/54262) (the primary post mentioned there got to revision #108…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rollback clears offensive flags. This is, and always has been, by design.

Comment: But it doesn't clear them in their entirety. I tried to flag the question as offensive again when I saw that for some reason the 10k tools thought there was no offensive flags. I was told I could only flag the question as offensive once.

Comment: This issue popped up again here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/232292#232292