# Why aren't rollbacks invalidating spam/rude flags?

Tags: support, flags, spam, offensive, rollbacks

According to [both](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032) [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876), rollbacks invalidate spam/rude flags. To test this theory and have the accurate representation of what the system does, I flagged [this answer as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/329041/revisions) and proceeded to roll it back to the previous revision. I expected the flag to be dismissed, but it wasn't. I rolled it back again to the revision that it has when I flagged it, still active.

Are roll back supposed to invalidate flags? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: One possible theory is that since I'm both the flagger and the editor it doesn't take into account my roll back, but that seems to be too complicated.

Comment: Another-nother theory is about the freshness of the post.

Comment: Or perhaps because it is a CW.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. considering that users can make answers CW, I don't see how the "expected behavior" could be abused by making answers CWed.

Comment: Option 4: You rolled back a rollback, instead of an edit.

Comment: Anyway, we're kind of coordinating on the Tavern to do science for this. Worst case, this question might be the target for the science, if you're okay...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I always wanted to be a ginea pig :D

Comment: R/A flag fired away. Any mods please note I do not actually find Braiam's question offensive!

Comment: Done edit for science, please don't rollback it first. Anyone is free to flag the question as rude because the last remark is quite rude...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. cast r/a flag as well. Mine is for real ;)

Comment: After rolling back to revision 3, both flags (from Spevacus and rene) stay... so something is definitely broken.

Comment: I've been scouring the code trying to figure out how this works since you posted it and... I cannot actually find any references in the current code that would even attempt to clear Spam/Offensive flags on a rollback. It doesn't appear to be broken more than completely removed, and I have no idea why.

Comment: @animuson Am I hearing the wheel of blame turning?

Comment: @animuson does the flag table stores the revision a flag was cast?

Comment: @Braiam It does not. I assume the way it worked was to grab the date off the revision being rolled back to and clear all the SpamOffensive flags past that date.

Comment: @animuson that smells like a potential racing condition.

Comment: Looking through old FAQ revisions, I can see that the idea that red flags get removed when a post is rolled back [was present in the rollback FAQ since its very first revision in 2008](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/18876/1). It's also been in the red flag FAQ since [its very first revision in 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/58035/1). I'm trying to see if it was mentioned on the blog somewhere, especially since it's so old and neither provides a source.

Comment: @animuson so should we edit the FAQ posts and remove the parts saying that rollback invalidates red flags?

Comment: I did some more research and found [this 2010 bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65621/377214) a rude/abusive flag (then known as an "offensive" flag) that had been cleared, and the answer from Jeff was that it was because of a rollback. That post did say that the spam flag remained while the offensive flag didn't, so perhaps that's how it works. I doubt that, though, given that both are stored internally using the same `SpamOffensive` class today. I think that offensive flags used to be stored differently at the time the posts were written and the code hasn't been adapted.

Answer (score 5):

#### Are roll backs supposed to invalidate flags? What is the expected behavior?

I don't think they should.

Reasoning - consider the following scenario.

1. Question/Answer contains a spam link or someone edits an existing post and adds some spammy bits and it gets flagged (good).
2. Someone edits to remove the spam link (bad - not supposed to do that as its discourage viewers from adding more spam flags as all it does is **hide** the spammy bits).
3. Someone else rolls back the edit (good - spam link is visible for future flaggers).

In this rollback case the initial spam flags should not be removed (they are still valid and should count towards the number of flags needed to auto delete).

A mod will also see the flags and can take appropriate action (which is perhaps to report to Smokey ([a headless chatbot that detects spam and posts it to chatrooms](https://charcoal-se.org/)), delete the post and destroy the spammer, have a quiet word with the person who edited out the spam, etc ...).

Comment: As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/) the flags cast on revision 1 would still be there, a rollback wouldn't necessarily invalidate those, only the ones users might cast on revision 2 without rolling back to 1 first (this exception is what sparked this post). The [reasoning here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207906/369802) for having this feature focuses on the reverse (good post gets spam/r/a edited in), though I wonder how much of a problem that really is: It would require a user with full editing privileges, or one without those and some very ignorant reviewers...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell As far as I know a spammer can post a spam free question/answer and then later make it spammy without it going through any review. As it is their question/answer no rep is needed. It is a potential corner case.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's true. I forgot about that one :-) I still wonder how much of a problem that really is though, then... and part of me wouldn't mind having such posts still spam-deleted then, if the only reason for posting them in the first place was to turn them into spam later.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell That (OP later editing spam into their post) is ... actually moderately common. It is done systematically (i.e. create multiple accounts; post, then edit in the spam anywhere from within the grace period to days later). I've destroyed a few such sets of accounts.

Comment: What @Makyen describes is (from what I understand) why the asker can't edit a deleted question. Someone could delete the question, edit in spam, wait two weeks, undelete... magic! Since the undeletion doesn't bump the post, no one is aware that the spam exists. So, we prevent editing.

Comment: Correct, @catija. It's not just bumping either; several other things make assumptions about time since last edit being the same as time visible on the site, even if the post was deleted for the majority of that time. It's one of those things that... Probably should be explicit, but would require a much more robust (and, uh, fast) history in order to do so - so we get little heuristics instead.