# Automatically lock posts heavily edited within a time frame

Tags: feature-request, moderation, locked-questions, rollback-wars

I liked [this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege/70035#70035) so much — and think it makes a poor 20k ability (sorry Andy) — that I'm suggesting it directly:

> Temporarily lock questions from being edited, to prevent ridiculous edit wars like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3852260/revisions).

This could be handled by automatically locking any post with E edits in T minutes.  It could be limited to just a day or two, then automatically unlocked, if moderators finding time to review the post is a concern.  However, it could require a new locking type, as I believe posting comments on these questions might still be useful.

For E=10, T=60, I don't remember any false positives (barring quickly-wiki'd, discussed below), but it would cover the mentioned case, the ["bomb effing USA" troll](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51400/need-moderator-attention-on-so-right-now) (okay, he used several posts, but it would've slowed him down and reduced frustration for *important* users), and others.

For the [quickly-wiki'd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46078/quick-edits-force-a-badly-formatted-post-to-wiki-within-minutes) problem, I [have a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/preventing-conflicting-simultaneous-edits/46118#46118) as well, which would eliminate them as false positives for this feature.

I expect E and T need tweaked, with an attempt at gauging effectiveness.

Comment: Even cooling it off for 1 hour would help.

Comment: I concur with @yhw42. Overall, though, an excellent idea.

Comment: I think giving the OP the final say and then transfering control to moderatore would be a good idea. Meaning OP can lock his own post, so that no one except a moderator or OP himself/herself can unlock the post for editing

Answer (score 7):

It's a good idea -- we had this slated during [The Great Edit Wars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/) but demand for it seemed to wane over time.

It's probably safe to auto-lock (for a set duration) based on a heuristic of a very large number of edits by a small # of users in a small amount of time.

Comment: Would a 1 hour cool-off period (for example) be triggered if a post is edited 5 times within 2 minutes? It is rare, but in the event that I continue to find grammatical errors or ways to clarify a question, would I trigger a cool-off?

Comment: @dboarman: That sounds like accidental conflicts (when a question is new) rather than intentional edits/reverts, and the latter is the focus of this.  Incidentally, the [linked suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/preventing-conflicting-simultaneous-edits/46118#46118) fixes those (as I'm sure other suggestions would as well), which should eliminate them from being false positives on the "edit war" trigger proposed here.

Answer (score 3):

Edit wars are so extremely rare that we don't need an automated system to deal with them.

Just wait until a moderator can jump in, usually it doesn't take very long.

Comment: I also thought about this, then realized I'd seen it happen three times with *plenty* of frustration and aggravation; even counting for only finding one through meta, how many times have I not seen it?  My usual 10:1 ratio to estimate that is still a drop in SO's bucket, but I'm throwing this out there because I think it could be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a better solution : the system should automatically cast a moderator attention flag when an edit war is taking place, but without locking the post.

Your current solution has the major downside of having a 50% luck of locking the post while it's on the wrong state, and then it'll stay in that wrong state until the lock times out. It may not be a big deal in that particular question, but when truly wrong and potentially dangerous information is at stake it becomes a real issue.

Comment: The system already does this when it detects a rollback war. The problem is that moderators aren't always online, and aren't always looking at the flags when they are online, so it may be a long time before they actually see the flag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn the only disruption caused by an edit war is just bumping the post up on the homepage, so we can disable that in case of such a war, but other than that I don't see what harm is caused by waiting for a moderator to solve the issue. Offensive/spam edits will be taken care of anyway (by flagging the post) even if a moderator isn't present.