# Why did my suggested edit get accepted without notifying me of the new edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unconditionally ask for confirmation before submitting an edit if one was just submitted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99535/unconditionally-ask-for-confirmation-before-submitting-an-edit-if-one-was-just-s)

I was typing an edit to a question's content on The Workplace and apparently submitted it very shortly after another edit had been made. The other edit was submitted at 04:54:52Z and I submitted mine at 04:55:18Z, so it was a difference of 26 seconds. I can understand that the edit notifier didn't pick up on it, but why when I manually submitted it did the system not stop the submission and give me a notice that another edit was made and I should review it? Why did it just accept my suggested edit, which backtracks some of his edits before making mine? The system had an entire 26 seconds to determine that...

I know this is a matter of a very short time, but even if it's only a couple of seconds, the server-side system should still be able to see there was a newer edit and not accept mine until I've reviewed it. My edit should never be accepted without *at least* notifying me that there was another edit, even if it is determined to be "more substantive."

- The [question's revision history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/1025/revisions)
- My [suggested edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/148)

<sub>P.S. This would be a great time to be able to retract suggested edits. ;)</sub>

Comment: Please use the site's Meta instead of MSO. The Workplace is brand new, we need Meta activity. I know chances are this will be resolved quicker on MSO, but per site Metas need all the love they can get. And there is a (small) chance this is a site specific bug (no there isn't).

Comment: @Yahoo, I feel using MSO for these kind of questions is more appropriate. Workplace states in the header: *got a question about the site itself? meta.workplace is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.*, and in its Meta FAQ: *The focus of this site is the content topic. If the question is about the Stack Exchange engine in a general sense, it should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow instead.*

Comment: @Arjan No, not really. Bug reports are perfectly valid for per site Metas, MSO is great for all of us who are accustomed with SO and know where to look, but remember that there are 85 sites right now and more are popping out from Area51 every day, not everyone knows MSO exists. Ideally people should always ask on the site's Meta for everything that isn't truly network wide.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast: Isn't it truly network-wide, though? I imagine the editing is the same across all the sites, and that Workplace.SE isn't the only one affected. (If it is a bug. Sometimes the diff algorithm can be a little off, it seems...)

Comment: @Arjan: I feel like any time you just accept it without even notifying the person that there was another edit is poor behavior.

Comment: Are you referring to waffle's explanation, @animuson? In that case I agree: it is very confusing, and even more: it can remove valuable information. I also wonder what voretaq7 was seeing when approving (and *improving*; causing Community the be shown as approving the edit) your suggested edit, much later at 05:14.38.

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, the problem in this instance is that the cycle to give me a notification while still editing didn't get to run, so apparently the server doesn't realize that and just assumes you know there was another edit and silently accepts it, so there is absolutely *no* notification whatsoever. I really dislike this. I think voretaq just re-applied his edits over the edits I made. Anywho, I'm going to change this to a feature request since apparently waffles *is* aware of it.