# Show an indication that question is being edited by someone else

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide indicator that another user is editing a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post)

When I see a poorly written or formatted question, I want to edit it and fix what's wrong. Problem is, I have no way of telling if someone else is has already started editing the question.

This is not a problem when the question is short. It's more of an annoyance if the question is long and takes a couple minutes to fix.

I propose a small box which is showed somewhere close to the question and says "x started editing the question y minutes ago".

This would make it less likely for multiple users to edit a question simultaneously. That usually ends up with all but one of the editors having a couple of their minutes wasted.