# Is there a better way to get revision source as-is?

Tags: support, revisions-list, api

I am wondering if there's a way to get the last post's revision source without these steps. Is there a more direct way?

- I need to ask the Stack Exchange API to give me the API site parameter
- I need to get revisions of current posts via the API
- I need to get that revision from `http://"+document.domain+"/revisions/"+revision_guid+"/view-source`, and parse the response (jQuery `$(response).filter("pre");`)

The `body` field from `/revisions/` (in the second step) just gives HTML response, which is not what I'm looking for.

For those wanting to know WHY do I want to do this, it's because I want to show post source under the current post.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't this type of question be asked on http://stackapps.com/questions ? (I'm not sure)

Comment: @Mat I wasn't actually sure, too

Comment: If its not already there I can userscript it :)

Comment: @Martin: I know, it was a bad meme joke :/

Comment: @Martin: Being a programmer site, wouldn't you expect `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/130017/-1` to point to `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/130017/3`? That would be a great way to implement this--negative-relative revision numbering. :)

Comment: For [my script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3211/stackscraper-export-questions-as-json-or-html) I found it simplest to copy the source out of the `/edit/` page, but that's not so great if you need to handle locked/uneditable posts.

Comment: @Twilight actually, no. What a great idea! Just a simple OT question: why does `$(response).filter("pre")` work in my code to find the raw source but `$("pre", response)` nor `$(response).find("pre")` doesn't? (gives me an empty array)

Answer (score 1):

@Twilight gave me an amazing idea of using edit page for this simple purpose.

This gets a source of question and answers:

```js
$(".question, .answer").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-questionid");
    if (!id) {
        id = $(this).attr("data-answerid");
    }
    $.get("http://"+document.domain+"/posts/"+id+"/edit-inline", function(t) {  
        // $(t).find("textarea").val() is the source
    });
});
```

Comment: Just for future readers, one drawback that Twilight noted: *"not so great if you need to handle locked/uneditable posts"*. I myself wonder if this would somehow increase some counters on the servers, like indicators that someone started editing. But I guess such counters would actually be based on true editing the text (like when a draft is saved). And I don't know of [any current functionality that would use such counters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post) to start with.