# My question was closed before I could update it

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My question is about this question on SO: [regex instead of replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967672/regex-instead-of-string-replace-function)

I've hit enter by accident and there was no way I could hide it or undo my "submit"
Now it is closed, what can I do about it instead of just waiting for it to be reopened?

Could there be something that you can display you're updating it?

Comment: Just finish to edit it and flag for re-opening, with your explanation.

Comment: Just make sure to write the title and the tags first, then if you hit Enter while in one of those textboxes you won't post anything as empty post is not allowed. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: people <10k can't access their deleted questions easily, that's slightly dangerous advice.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You're right.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I don't think a link is sufficient for deleted Qs. (But maybe self-deletes are ok.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's not re-opened in a couple of hours, you should flag for moderation attention, explain to the moderators that you've updated the answer and ask them to review your edits and re-open it.

Comment: Well, I understand that's a way. But still for any question, I think there could be something displaying like: "The question is being edited at this moment"

Comment: @Robuust Bad idea, and it probably _won't_ save the question from getting closed, I'd go as far as to say that it might even encourage close votes and downvotes (people generally don't like sloppiness - or what might appear as sloppiness). How about you just be a bit more careful next time?

Comment: @Robuust it was already [suggested and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I did not know that, thanks :)