# Please add 'refresh post' button to edit conflict page

Tags: feature-request

While editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5714618/revisions), I lost [an edit conflict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts/28119#28119) by a few seconds. I went back to the main list of questions *and didn't find the question by searching for the old question name*. Maybe it was on the next page, maybe the title had changed. (Not in this case, it had just fallen off the first 50 posts.)

We have friendly 'refresh post' links in the edit approval popup, a 'return to post' link in the edit history, but where I would find it most useful is after losing edit conflicts. Adding a nice `diff` between the edit that won and my edit-in-potentia would be a super-sweet feature: maybe I want to overwrite the edit, maybe the edit is an improvement. A `diff` would help me know which is which. :)

But if a `diff` is too much, maybe a humble 'refresh post' link would suffice?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting that "refresh" to do? If it loads the most recent version, your changes would be lost?

Comment: (As a workaround: holding down Ctrl or Command while clicking the browser's Back button, will often open the previous page in a new tab or window. That might get you to the question again, which you can then refresh to see the latest version, or from which you can click through to the revision history.)

Comment: @Arjan, while I would expect `return to question` to throw away my edit, I keep thinking that something to show me _my edit_ and the edit that won would be best; either re-using the `review/suggested-edits` diff tool, or AJAX-pushing the source or rendered question into the page next to my edit, or something more clever :) would be _best_. Maybe I can live with the back button until then :) -- but it seems strange the friendly link is missing here, but available elsewhere.