# Editing a question whilst it is retagged by the poster attributes the retagging to the Editor

Tags: support, edits

I recently edited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911610/i-am-trying-to-combine-two-table-master-and-child-in-one-i-need-only-one-recor). Just some basic code formatting and a few spelling mistakes.

Whilst I was in the process of editing the literal "This post has been edited 1 times" appeared above the title.

I completed the edit and it stated it was awaiting peer approval as per usual.

I then clicked on the link that stated the post had been edited 48s earlier. This then showed me that the user who had posted the question had added a couple of tags.

My edit was approved and A couple of minutes later I was awarded the [Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer) badge even though I didn't do the re-tagging.

A small bug I know but I thought it better reported than not.

**Edit :**

I was just reading the following [Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts) about concurrent edits.

The answer seems to suggest that checks are in place (note I could be reading a post that is now out of date). Though I'm unsure to whether the warning messages reporting a conflicting edit would show when the user saves his edits Or when the peer confirms them?

Comment: "It's not a bug. It's a feature!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened here was that the user edited their question to *add* a tag ([sql-server2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server2008)) while you were still working on your edit. Since you were working on a version of the question that didn't have that tag, saving your edit removed it again. Since you ultimately *did* remove a tag, you got the Organizer badge.

Comment: Makes complete sense, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Though removing that tag here could be considered as a bug, because it *had* been added and not been removed. It got removed just because the editing UI you saw was not up to date...

Comment: @Spontifixus That applies to the entire question though (not just the tags). If someone edits the body of the question to add something, it is lost when you save your edits.

Comment: @Asad wasn't there a lock so a question could be edited only by one person in time, that 1) disabled the links to edit and retag whilst there is an edit in progress and 2) that led to an error page when submitting an edit to a post that had been edited in the meantime?

Comment: @Spontifixus As far as 1 is concerned, no, not unless there's been recent changes I'm unaware of. There's a stagnant feature request about that somewhere. As far as 2 is concerned that only happens if your edit is less "substantial" than the edit that interrupts you.

Comment: I was just reading the following [Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/notifications-for-concurrent-changes-when-editing-posts) about concurrent edits. The answer seems to suggest that checks are in place (note I could be reading a post that is now out of date). Though I'm unsure to whether the warning messages reporting a conflicting edit would show when the user saves his edits Or when the peer confirms them?